# djangocms Currently installed Django version 3.2.15 differs from the declared 3.1

Tags: python, django, pip, django-cms

I am running an AWS Bitnami Django instance. Django 3.2.15 installed by default. Django documentation recommends version django 3.2 so all is good there. Once installed I am having a hard time getting djangocms to create a new project. I keep getting dependency errors when I issue the command

```
djangocms -f -p . projectname
```

I received the following:

```
Currently installed Django version 3.2.15 differs from the declared 3.1. Please check the given `--django-version` installer argument, your virtualenv configuration and any package forcing a different Django version
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why I was receiving these errors when I knew I had more recent versions installed and followed the documentation correctly. Following these steps should get the issue resolved, it is what worked for me:

```
cd /home/projects-folder/
rm -R myproject/
rm -R venv/ (if you used a virtualenv)
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install django-cms
pip install djangocms-installer
```

If you didn't use a virtualenv LOG OUT! LOG IN! Without logging out the site-packages will not reflect changes made.

If you are using a virtualenv I highly recommend removing the env, deleting the env folder and start all over with a new virtualenv. This was definitely frustrating for me so hopefully this can be of help to someone.